# Не удаляется динамически созданный контент

Tags: javascript

На странице по клику, средствами Js, создается контейнер.
При следующем клике - контейнер следует удалить. Функция ниже не срабатывает:

```
$(document).on("click", '.answer', function(event) {

    if (($(".commentReview").length > 0)){
         $(".commentReview").remove();
    }
```

Comment: Создайте тестовый пример на jsfiddle.net. Вполне возможно у вас где-то опечатка в коде, который мы не видим.

Comment: Pojaluista: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6LLx/

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk сделайте пример чтобы он работал неправильно а не вообще не работал как сейчас!

Comment: Ispravil: http://jsfiddle.net/RHZpb/4/

Comment: Я не вижу проблем. Вроде бы [работает нормально][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Q6LLx/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RHZpb/5/  при повторном клике не скрывается текст

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk [так](http://jsfiddle.net/RHZpb/6/) понятней будет?

Comment: При повторном клике должен удаляться блок .commentReview

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, (spoiler alert) он и удаляется, он просто создается заново тут же.